# Is url og tag necessary if I don't want Facebook to ignore this page

Tags: html, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

On of the OG meta tags is the `url` property. We'd use that if the info we want rendered is on another URL.

However if we don't want to redirect the bot to another URL - i.e. the info on the scraped page is correct - do we still need to define the OG-tag?

Comment: i guess facebook will just use the current url then, but why not just ALWAYS add it?

Comment: "Hello Joe, what's your name?" just feels a bit reduntant..